# Should tags [filter] and [filtering] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request, filtering

Should the tags [filter](/questions/tagged/filter) and [filtering](/questions/tagged/filtering) be merged? The former has no wiki summary, but seems intended for the same purpose as the latter.

Comment: You mean here on MSE or on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I mean here on MSE.

Comment: So yes and no: [meta-tag:filter] should not exist in my opinion, but not everything fits the [meta-tag:filtering], some refer to the network filtered questions, some refer to sorting... it needs a manual decision per question.

Comment: Close voter: this is talking about tags **here in MSE**, please read the question before voting to close.

Comment: Looks like [filter] no longer exists (EDIT – Related discussion: [Let's disambiguate / burninate \[filter\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341527/335251)), but [filtering] still does... That said, [filtering] probably shouldn't exist either. The questions that currently have the tag should probably be retagged with more appropriate tags.